# Adding a new column for a certain condition for a combination of two column values in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I have 3 columns in the table with last column as "Status" . I want the table to be grouped and to add a new column "Final Status" . Final Status should be "fail" if for any dept_id and session_id combination , the status is fail in original table.

My data and expected results looks like below :

```
Dept_id   Session_id   Status
a         S1           Pass
a         S1           Pass 
a         S1           Fail
b         S1           Pass
b         S1           Pass
c         S1           Fail
a         S2           Pass
a         S2           Pass
```

Expected Results :

```
Dept_id    Session_id    Final_Status
a          S1            Fail
b          S1            Pass 
c          S1            Fail
a          S2            Pass
```

Explanation - Since for combination "a" and "S1" , there is a Status as "Fail" so final status is fail and for combination "b" and "S1" , there is no Status as Fail so Final_Status is pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this answer:

`df.replace({'Pass':True,'Fail':False}).groupby(['Dept_id', 'Session_id']).all().reset_index().replace({'True':'Pass','False':'Fail'})`